# Build error : library not found for -lRNTuneSDKBridge xcode 10, React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10

In xcode 10 I am able to build the project in debug mode but in Release mode, build failed with the following error.

**ld: library not found for -lRNTuneSDKBridge
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

I am developing the project with React Native. It was working fine in xcode 9, after updating xcode this error comes.

Any one faced this problem? How can I resolve it?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change to old build system -> File -> Workspace Settings -> Change to
   Legacy build system. Reinstall npm.

Comment: Did the same but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the package to the library. Just follow this steps: 
1- Drag and drop the iOS file of package TuneSDKBridge inside the library in Xcode
2- add it in both build phase and build setting

For more information you can find everything in the following link:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries-ios

I hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you Reza for the reply, I have already followed the the process of Automatic linking and the library is linked and build works in debug mode too.